# Jython how to return input screen

Tags: websphere, jython

I'm a sysadmin, I'm a newbie in coding, please help me to verify code. I'm going to build menu websphere to restart cluster based on code of script that I found from Pavan Devarakonda.

```
### Script ###

def menu():
 printBorder()
 print """ Cluster Control Menu
 1. Show Cluster status
 2. Stop Cluster
 3. Start Cluster
 4. Return input cluster
 5. Exit Menu

 """
 printBorder()
 choice=input("Select choice: ")
 return choice

#  Main program
cls()
cellName=AdminControl.getCell()
cluster=raw_input("Please enter cluster name: ")
clusterObj = AdminControl.completeObjectName('cell='+ cellName +',type=Cluster,name='+ cluster +',*')

#nodeName=AdminControl.getNode()
#node=raw_input("Please enter node name: ")
#server=raw_input("Please enter server name: ")
#nodeObj = AdminControl.completeObjectName('node='+ nodeName +',type=Server,name='+ server +',*')
while 1:
 ch=menu()
 if ch == 1:
  print cluster, " state is ", clusterStatus(clusterObj)
 elif ch == 2:
  print "stopping the cluster member servers"
  stopCluster(cellName, clusterObj)
  print "After stopping "+ cluster +"status ...", clusterStatus(clusterObj)
 elif ch==3:
  print "start cluster selected...."
  startCluster(cellName, clusterObj)
  print "After stopping "+ cluster +"status ...", clusterStatus(clusterObj)
 elif ch==4:
  cluster=""
  clusterObj=""
  print cluster
  print "Return input cluster step"
  cluster1=input("Please input new cluster name:")
  cluster1=cluster
 elif ch==5:
  print "Exit from menu..."
  break
```

With choice 4: I want to return input screen. But seem code is wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you get an error when you run it ? If so, add the error output to your question.

Comment: When I choose no 4 then Input new cluster name. It Ouput error related to line :"cluster1=cluster"  - NameError: name 'cls_AppSrv01' is not defined